# How to close and save a fully opened file in Python?

Tags: python, excel, csv

How do you close/save a file in Python that was opened using `os.startfile` ?

I used `os.startfile` to simulate a double click in explorer because I need excel to input the data connected sheets before closing and saving. The only way that seems to work is by fully opening the file.

Is it possible to save and close it after? Or at least save and then kill the excel process?

Comment: So, what you're actually looking for is a way to remotely control excel after you've opened a file with [os.startfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.startfile)? I see the documentation recommends the subprocess module to have more control. Have you looked into that? But there are other ways to remotely control windows applications, such as [pywinauto](https://pywinauto.github.io/). Still, if that's what you want, I'd recommend updating your question, especially the title, to more closely reflect what you are looking for.

Comment: from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.startfile): "There is no option to wait for the application to close, and no way to retrieve the application’s exit status."  I'm pretty sure that means that once the action is started with `os.startfile` you don't really have any more control over what happens.

Comment: thanks, if it were possible for it to update linked data without having the source files open completely at the same time I'd use something else. But I'll try pywinauto that might work too.